# Android in-app purchases are coming back cancelled

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I've been working on implementing in-app billing, basing it off of blundell's tutorial here: http://www.anddev.org/advanced-tutorials-f21/simple-inapp-billing-payment-t52060.html

When I go to make a purchase, everything seems to check out fine, however after a few minutes I get a notification that the purchase failed and is cancelled.  The message I get back looks like this:

We could not complete your order in a timely fashion. Please verify your payment information in Google Checkout and try again later.

So I took a look using LogCat, and it looks like when I get the IN_APP_NOTIFY action, it's simply coming back cancelled.  I am totally stumped, and I've had other people try on their devices with the same issue.

It's not listed below, but in the JSON string I get back, purchaseState is set to 1 (cancelled).

Log dump!

```
    06-05 17:39:03.175: INFO/BillingService(7694): Received action: com.android.vending.billing.IN_APP_NOTIFY
    06-05 17:39:03.175: INFO/BillingService(7694): getPurchaseInformation()
    06-05 17:39:03.183: INFO/BillingService(7694): current request is:1874091953267766809
    06-05 17:39:03.183: INFO/BillingService(7694): GET_PURCHASE_INFORMATION Sync Response code: RESULT_OK
    06-05 17:39:03.714: INFO/BillingService(7694): Received action: com.android.vending.billing.PURCHASE_STATE_CHANGED
    06-05 17:39:03.714: INFO/BillingService(7694): got signedData
    06-05 17:39:03.757: INFO/BillingService(7694): confirmTransaction()
    06-05 17:39:03.765: INFO/BillingService(7694): CONFIRM_NOTIFICATIONS Sync Response code: RESULT_OK
    06-05 17:39:03.768: INFO/ConcertView(7694): Transaction complete
    06-05 17:39:03.768: INFO/ConcertView(7694): Transaction status: CANCELED
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out my own issue - it looks like the tutorial mentioned uses the android 1.6 version of sending the PendingIntent from a purchase request.  I had to switch it to the 2.0 version.

It of course says this in the comments, but apparently I blew right past it.  Facepalm.